# Are claims that Elon Musk cannot back out of buying Twitter after agreeing to buy before actually doing so valid without a full deposit in escrow?

Tags: contract-law, securities

> Elon Musk must close Twitter deal by end of this week or face trial. (CNN Business, October 24th, 2022)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does requiring Musk's personal ownership of the company have to do with fraudulent stipulation? what makes this requirement a fraudulent stipulation? Most important: what are the relevant portions of his contract (or draft of contract) with Twitter? It seems futile to speculate on what a contract *would* require, since that largely depends on (1) what the parties have in mind and (2) the likelihood of persuading the counterparty to include that clause.

Comment: I'm asking about the requirement of a deposit in contracts to create obligations generally.  The obligation of Musk to buy twitter is interesting to me. I chore as a bookkeeper for a home contracting company and also have contracted scope of requirements without product recompense for dissolution **unless as a deposit**. I'm also product research for [scopes.cc](https://scopebook.quora.com)

Comment: Possibly relevant to @Iñaki Viggers comment, that site you do product research for seems to be a Q and A site with all or most of the questions by you and not many answers.

Comment: George, you can use the biography to read about the product I am developing. A contract is just an option to buy, there is no obligation but for the lost theta credit premium, at least in options trading.

Answer (score 2):

### I don’t know, I haven’t read it

It might require a deposit. It might not.

There is no need for a deposit to make a contract binding.

Comment: So then what does a deposit for purchase do?

Comment: @NickCarducci it gives the recipient money before they do their contractural obligations, normally, you don’t get paid until after you do the work, with a deposit you do.

Comment: Is the buyer so obligated then to pay for a *substandard* product that limits the price by said contract?

Comment: @NickCarducci I don’t know, I haven’t read it. People are free to contract Dow whatever they want subject to the law. There is no consumer protection on this sort of contract so whatever they agreed to is what they have to do

Comment: A deposit is usually there to pay one party for immediate damages if the other party is in breach of a contract, especially if the other party is in breach of contract and has no money to pay for damages. There may be a clause in the contract that you can walk away from it and just lose your deposit; otherwise the damaged party can still hold you to your contract.

Answer (score 1):

A contract can specify that a deposit is required before some obligation is effective. Or it can fail to include any such requirement, in whch case no deposit is needed. In some kinds of contract, such as house purchases, a deposit is usual.But even in a transaction where a deposit is usual, it may be omitted from the contract, if the parties so agree.

An option to buy normally gives one party the right to make a specified purchase at a specified price within a specified time. There need not be a deposit, although there could be. There does need to be some consideration to make the contract valid (in a common-law jurisdiction). This is often a purchase price for the *option*. But it can be small, even nominal, and is separate from any deposit.

A deposit give one party some assurance tht the other party is serious about a transaction. Often it will be forfeited, in whole or in part, if the party giving the deposit fails to proceed without good reason. But that depends on the terms of the contract, and perhaps on specific law that applies to the transaction, particularly in consumer transactions (which any sale of Twitter is surely not).

I knpw of no law that **requires** a deposit for a contract to be binding in any situation, although there could be one I do not know of. Inb commo-law systems there must generally be **some** consideration for a contract to be binding, but this need not take the form of a deposit.

I do not see what the relevance of a "Fraudulent stipulation" mentioned in the question would be.

Comment: *Fraudulent stipulation*; donee beneficiary credit, an admittance of exclusion from markets as supply. Consumer protections over a scope of requirements. **Overtime implied change orders**. `…purchase price for the option. …separate from any deposit[, … that] give(s) one party some assurance tht the other party is serious about a transaction. Often it will be forfeited, in whole or in part, if the party giving the deposit fails to proceed without good reason… that applies to consumer transactions (which any sale of Twitter is surely not).` Why a security not subject to declarative fraud law?

Comment: *The holding invites cost*. Like, I say “shipping is incumbent for lost packages, but not necessarily damaged[ ones],” as so implied (but for non-minimal-viable-duress).

Comment: @Nick Carducci I still do not see what a deposit has to do with fraud law. Nor do I see what you mean by "*Overtime implied change orders.*" which seems to have no relevance to the question or my answer at all, indeed no definite meaning. In any case I do not see any need to change the answer I gave.

Comment: A *deposit is forfeited if it fails to proceed (without good reason like Overtime implied change orders)*, except for securities, to which the off-exchange purchase price is instead compulsory [perhaps because it's intangible, non-concurrentable, good-will (*and all that fiducially under its name*) with no loss of confidence in the optional price?]. The buyer of the option is to (not) execute (as such is the valued benefit utility of the premium credit bungle), for it is deliverable; the broadness of **scope of requirements begs fraud** law, however, until subjective-completion final payment.